# Magento 2.1: Trigger event after "super-attribute-select" is populated

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1

I have a bunch of configurable products with just one attribute each.

I need to select the first product in the super-attribute-select <select> box (e.g. the second <option>).

This code works from the console...

```
jQuery('select.super-attribute-select option:nth-of-type(2)').prop('selected', 'selected');
jQuery('select.super-attribute-select').change();
```

...but not from document.ready, as the <select> box is only populated after the page loads.

Does anyone know the proper technique for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nshiff for their help. Here is my less than satisfactory but working solution:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("super-attribute-select").arrive("option", function() {
    $('select.super-attribute-select option:nth-of-type(2)').prop('selected', 'selected');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('select.super-attribute-select').change();
    }, 250);
});
```

For some reason (I think something to do with require.js) arrive.js isn't registering itself with jQuery, so I'm having to use a good old getElementsByClassName. There's a timeout in there because if I triggered the change() too early it wasn't being picked up.

Comment: As a programmer I hate timeout.
But I need to create a push on external system sending the "size" of products and the only why I found (I can't ask it to web agency) was:
- tracking the click on size (<li>)
- get the select value after 250 ms

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where an extension was loading its elements after the document load event. You could solve this in a cheesy way with a setTimeout and wait 2 seconds or something after the page loads.

The way I solved it was by using this community [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) library.

```
jQuery(document).arrive('.something .new', function() {
    console.log('Oh hey, this element just appeared.');
});
```

Go ahead and take a peek at examples of optimization (not watching the entire DOM tree), but yeah, in essence, you are registering a custom event to fire whenever the new element loads, specified by a normal CSS selector. As I said, this worked in a case similar to yours where elements were not yet loaded at document ready.

Comment: Thanks! I did consider the timeout approach, but as you say it's both cheesy and arbitrary (e.g. if there's a delay in receiving the AJAX response)

Comment: The problem with arrive.js is I'm not waiting for an element to be added, but rather changed (the select box already exists, but is empty). Perhaps I could trigger it on creation of an option inside the select box, but if there are multiple options to be added I'm not sure if that would mess things up...

Comment: @Geat I think you can add a CSS selector to account for that.

Comment: Oops sorry, posted too soon. For example: jQuery(document).arrive('select option[selected="selected"]'). It's pretty cool, jQuery allows you to target arbitrary attributes of an element. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Yeah, for sure, but don't forget the select will only have a selected option *after* I trigger the code I need to using arrive.js.

Comment: I think that's okay. You just have to outline the order in which things happen. First command: `jQuery('select.super-attribute-select option:nth-of-type(2)').length` this returns a number in the console, but zero during document ready? That means that you can set up the arrive event to happen when that element is populated. (Unless I'm still misunderstanding what you're saying.) `jQuery('select.super-attribute-select option:nth-of-type(2)').arrive(function(){console.log('Yay, populated!')})` I imagine you will play with the selectors a bit, but I think it's possible.